# Excel refresh fails on OneDrive for Business

Tags: excel, refresh, onedrive, powerquery

My excel workbook has the following solution implemented:

The solutions is to loop through multiple excel files on OneDrive into one. The excel has the following sheets:

> Sheet1(Home Page): This has a table with a Key-Value pair. Key stands for the department and value is the path of the files on SharePoint

[image: Home Sheet]

> Sheet2: This sheet has the data from all the files mentioned in the Sheet1.

This is implemented using the power query. I’ve created a custom function in Power query to loop through the files in the table mentioned above and get the data.
The function to pull the data looks like this:

[image: Function Definition to Get data]

This solution works perfectly when I refresh from my excel desktop. 
When I place the file on one drive and open the same excel on the browser and hit refresh connection I see the following error:

[image: Error when refreshing the connection of browser]

Inputs on troubleshooting this error will be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if your screenshots had less whitespace a readable text. Can you please crop the white space and post the error message bigger?

Comment: Hello, Teylyn, Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the pictures.

Comment: Power Query does not work in Excel online. It only works in Excel for desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Excel Online does not support Power Query. You can have a data model and use pivot tables based on that data model in Excel Online, but you cannot refresh Power Queries or external data sources when you open the file in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for coming back Teylyn. Is there a way for me to have a excel sheet that contains the list of file paths and refresh to pull the data from all the files mentioned on the sheet and dump into another sheet (all files are of same format). The end goal is to use this excel sheet that has combined data as the source to PowerBI dashboard. The excel hosted on sharepoint should refresh automatically since the data in the file can change. Any suggestions on this? The option of using an ETL tool/ database is ruled out.

Comment: If the goal is to use the data in Power BI, then it would make a lot more sense to have the queries in Power BI, where they can be refreshed inside Power BI or through the data gateway. If you have the queries in Excel, then you have to open Excel and refresh the queries to refresh the data.

Comment: Agreed. The same solution is implemented on PowerBI as well. But the refresh from PowerBI web fails since it says "Unsupported datasource"

Comment: That is something you may want to take to the Power BI forum at http://community.powerbi.com/ - you will find a community that is much more focused on Power BI topics than Stackoverflow